# How can I change custom settings field visibility which contains sensitive data to private or protected?

Tags: managed-package, metadata, security-review

In the process of getting a managed package reviewed and it has been flagged for Insecure Storage of Sensitive Data and highlight the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customSettingsType>List</customSettingsType>
    <enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Client_Id__c</fullName>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Client Id</label>
        <length>100</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Client_Secret__c</fullName>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Client Secret</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>TextArea</type>
    </fields>
    <label>ConnectedApp</label>
    **<visibility>Public</visibility>**
</CustomObject>
```

**Notes**
Sensitive data like Client_Id__c and Client_Secret__c which is use in api call, should be stored in a protected custom setting or named credential.

**Related Code**

```
public class CRMA_AuthenticationCheck {
    ...
    @AuraEnabled
    public static ResponseWrapper authorizeCRMA(String session_id, String userId, String consumerSecret){
        ResponseWrapper rw = new ResponseWrapper();
        string successMsg;
        string crmaUrl;
        ConnectedApp__c conApp;
        try{
            Boolean isStaging = [SELECT Id, IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
            if(isStaging){
                crmaUrl = 'https://salesforcestaging.mydummysite.com/index.php/logincb/';
            }else{
                crmaUrl = 'https://salesforce.mydummysite.com/index.php/logincb/';
            }
            conApp = ConnectedAppCreator.createConnectedApp(crmaUrl+userId);
            Boolean isSuccess = false;
            if(String.isBlank(consumerSecret)){
                consumerSecret = conApp.Client_Secret__c;
            }
            if(String.isBlank(consumerSecret)){
                rw.StatusCode = 120;
                rw.ResponseMessage = 'Please Enter the Consumer Secret from Connected App with name Foo Connected App' ;
                rw.toastType = 'dismissable';
                return rw;
            }else {
                conApp.Client_Secret__c = consumerSecret;
            }
            if(conApp != null && String.isNotBlank(conApp.Client_Id__c)){
                successMsg = ConnectedAppDetailsToCRMA.connectedAppDetails(conApp.Client_Id__c, consumerSecret,UserInfo.getOrganizationName(), userId, session_id);
                
                if(successMsg == 'SUCCESSFUL'){
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
        return rw;
    }
    ...
}
```

Don't see how we can modify the field visibility to private or protected given that the definitions xml file are generated and we are not specifically defining a ConnectedApp.  Any link or relevant samples are appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a Public Custom Setting Protected once you've uploaded it at least once in a "Release" (not "Beta") package version. You will need to follow the directions in [Revert a managed package to a beta version](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312548&type=1) to fix this problem, or delete the Custom Setting entirely as outlined in [Delete Components from First-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm). Either way, you'll need to create a new, Protected Custom Setting or Named Credential.